# How Count Posts By Category In A Post Type?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have already tried this code:

```
$cats = get_terms('category');
$counts_by_term = wp_list_pluck( $cats, 'count', 'slug' );
echo $counts_by_term['uncategorized'];
```

But the problem is that, the category taxonomy is shared to every post type.

**Situation:**

I have a CPT called Testimonials and enabled the category and created a single post there with uncategorized category.
I also have 5 posts in post post type, all have uncategorized category assigned to them.

Now, I just want to get the number of posts with uncategorized category only from Testimonials post type.

The code above will output: **6**

Which should only be: **1**

Answer (score 0):

here's my solutions,

```
$cat_id = 1;
$post_type = 'testimonials'; 
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'category' => $cat_id,
    'post_type' => $post_type,
);
$count_posts = get_posts( $args );
$total_posts = count($count_posts);
echo $total_posts;
```

Answer (score 0):

//This would run with less stress to your Database

```
$cat_id = 1;
$args = array(
'category'=>$cat_id,
'post_type'=>'testimonials',
);
$postTypes = new WP_Query($args);
$numberOfPosts = $postTypes->found_posts;
echo $numberOfPosts;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$cats = get_terms('category', array('hide_empty' => false,  'show_count' => 1, 'orderby'=>'id', 'order' => 'ASC' )); //in array args put what you want

foreach($cats as $cat):
       echo $cat->count; // return total posts in your custom post type category with  'show_count' => 1, 
endforeach;
```